# JavaScript Instant Search Div Hiding With Fading Effect

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, search

I have implemented an instant search with javascript, i am able to make it work except at one point.

I have Implemented following in my instant search and are working fine.

1. result comes in "search-result" div.
2. when clicking anywhere on document result disapper.
3. when hover over or clicking in input field result reapper.
4. added fading effect on result reappear after document click.

This 1. Implementation not working fine.

added fading effect on result disapper after document click. It is working for first time when document is clicked result disapper with fading effect but after mouse hover or clicking input field result re appear, then on clicking document result do not disapper and no effect.

These are my Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showResult(str)
    {
        if (str.length==0)
        {
            document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="0px";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
                document.getElementById("search-result").autocomplete="off";
                document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
                var fired = false;

                document.onclick = function(){
                    close_box();
                    if(!fired){
                        document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){
                        show_box_fadeIn()
                        delete this.onmouseenter;};
            };
        }
        document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseleave = function(){
            var fired = true;
            if(fired){
                document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){
                show_box()};
        };
    }

    document.getElementById("search-input").onclick = function(e){
        if(!e) {
            e = window.event;
        }
        if(e.stopPropagation && e.preventDefault) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.returnValue = false;
        }show_box(); return true;
    };

    //////////EVENTS AFTER DOCUMENT ONCLICK//////////
    var fired = false;
    var closeBox = false;
    document.onclick = function(){
        if(!closeBox){
            close_box_fadeOut();
        }
        if(!fired){
            document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){
                show_box_fadeIn()
                delete this.onmouseenter;};
            };
        }
        document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseleave = function()
        {
            var fired = true;
            if(fired){
                document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){show_box()};
            };
        }
        }
        }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","instant-search.php?keyword="+str,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
       } 



    //////////FUNCTIONS//////////
    function show_box(){
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";

    }
    function show_box_fadeIn(){
        setOpacity( 0 );
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
        fadeIn()
    }
    function close_box(){
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="none";
    }
    function close_box_fadeOut(){
        if(closeBox){
            document.onclick = function(){close_box();}
            return;
        }
        closeBox = true;    
        setOpacity( 100 );
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
        fadeOut();
        setTimeout(close_box, 800);
    }
    function setOpacity( value ) {
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.opacity = value / 10;
        document.getElementById("search-result").style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 10 + ')';
    }
    function fadeIn() {
        for( var i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )
        setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (i / 10) + ')' , 10 * i );
    }
    function fadeOut() {
        for( var i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) 
        setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (10 - i / 10) + ')' , 8 * i );
    }
</script>
```

html codes.

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" size="50" id="search-input" value = 'Search'; onkeydown="showResult(this.value)" /></br></br>
```

Please suggest any possible way to do this, I hope someone out there can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Man, I'm not going to try to reindent your mess again. Try to post something nicer or else you'll hardly get an answer. Also, try to sum up your problem, don't post the parts that actually work.

Comment: I tried asking just my problem and got a working solution but when implementing it in my codes it didn't work that's why i put up my hole code for better understanding. hope you understand.

Comment: also i didnt know much of javascript and i tried very hard to make it work this long.

Comment: "Your code" is a patchwork of snippets by various authors, plus your own code. If you want to make your code actually work, not relying on some common framework (like jQuery or whatever), use the tutorials to _learn_ the stuff, then try to build your code by yourself, giving it a more organic look. It will be easier to read and maintain for you, and everybody else too.

Comment: got it, i didnt find any tutorials to lean from so took some thing from every where i can found and sum it together for implementation.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. There's no tutorial for the exact same thing you want to do. Now I'll be blunt, please don't take offence at it: your coding style is cranky and primitive, and desperately needs to be updated. I spotted at least 3 different coding styles in your snippet: you cut & pasted other's work, so you're a beginner. Then don't try to do complex things like this or, if you must, use jQuery or some other frameworks that do most of the job for you. And test your stuff not only in Internet Explorer if it's going to meet the public.

Comment: You are right i am a beginner and still learning. thanks for all your valuable advice. i didn't use jQuery for this because it is a simple thing with few lines of code, if i were to have more javascript functionality then ill definitely use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally, Hope this help others too.

```
    function showResult(str)
{
 if (str.length==0)
 {
    document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="0px";
    return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("search-result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    document.getElementById("search-result").autocomplete="off";
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
    var fired  = false;
    var closeBox = false;
    document.onclick = function()
     {
        if(closeBox){
        return;
        }else{close_box_fadeOut();closeBox = true;}
        if(!fired)
        {
    document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){
        show_box_fadeIn();  delete this.onmouseenter;};
        };
     }
    document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseleave = function()
     {
        var fired = true;
        if(fired){
              document.getElementById("search-input").onmouseenter = function(){show_box()};
                 };closeBox = false;
      }
    document.getElementById("search-input").onclick = function(e)
     {
        if(!e) {
        e = window.event;
        }

        if(e.stopPropagation && e.preventDefault) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        } else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = false;
        }show_box(); return true;
     }
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","instant-search.php?keyword="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function show_box(){
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
}
function show_box_fadeIn(){
    setOpacity( 0 );
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
    fadeIn()
}
function close_box(){
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="none";
}
function close_box_fadeOut(){
    setOpacity( 100 );
    document.getElementById("search-result").style.display="block";
    fadeOut();
    setTimeout(close_box, 400);
}
function setOpacity( value ) {
 document.getElementById("search-result").style.opacity = value / 10;
 document.getElementById("search-result").style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 10 + ')';
}
function fadeIn() {
 for( var i = 10 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )
   setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (i / 5) + ')' , 5 * i );
}
function fadeOut() {
 for( var i = 10 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) 
   setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (6 - i / 6) + ')' , 6 * i );
}
```